# How do I escape a single quote in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is below:

```
DECLARE @QueryText as NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @QueryText= 'select '"' + m.MACHINE_STREET + '"' AS MACHINE_LOCATION
                 from tblMachine m 
                 where m.Site= ''TSN'''

EXEC sp_Machine_Location,NULL,NULL,NULL,@QueryText
```

I had escaped the single quote in TSN by doubling them. But I don't know how can I achieve in MACHINE_STREET as I am picking the whole machine street within quotes otherwise it will break when exporting to Excel.

Comment: You double the quote in the string.  So, `''''` is a string containing one single quote.

Comment: warning: this is often a sign of an sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: ''"''+m.MACHINE_STREET+''"'' AS MACHINE_LOCATION is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to make double quotes surrounded by two single quotes to get the data in 
`MACHINE_STREET` between double quotes.

```
DECLARE @QueryText AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @QueryText= 'select ''"''+m.MACHINE_STREET+''"'' AS MACHINE_LOCATION
from tblMachine m where m.Site=''TSN'''
```

And I don't see any need of dynamic query here you can just do this

```
SELECT '"' + m.MACHINE_STREET + '"' AS MACHINE_LOCATION
FROM   tblMachine m
WHERE  m.Site = 'TSN'
```

Comment: @LT268, what error are you getting? The generated SQL code is correct so perhaps there is an issue in the called proc?

Comment: The job is completing without fetching any results. If i remove this field from my query and pass on another field without any escape strings, it successfully call the store pro and returning results. So i dont think any issue with store pro.

Comment: @LT268 - Do you have any record with `m.Site='TSN'`

Comment: @LT268 - Then this query will return two records check while exporting if there are some filters

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

This procedure allows you pass it the sql command the parameter data separately, such that you are somewhat protected from sql injection attacks.

Comment: There is no input passed to that query dynamically how did you assume the possibility of sql injection

Comment: The value in the `m.MACHINE_STREET` column came from somewhere.

Comment: It is a column from `tblMachine` table, while exporting to excel if there is a comma  in `MACHINE_STREET` column it could break the excel formatting. So OP want to append `"` around the data of `MACHINE_STREET` column